# se the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation

Tags: asp.net, security, eventvalidation

guys, I have a usercontrol in my asp.net 3.5 application and I am passing some plain text on button click event. button is situated in the usercontrol. but when I fire the event, I am getting the following error;

> Invalid postback or callback argument.
>   Event validation is enabled using
>   
>   in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a
>   page.  For security purposes, this
>   feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate
>   from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data
>   is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation
>   method in order to register the
>   postback or callback data for
>   validation.

when I set the EnableEventValidation="false" to web form page like blow. it fires the event;

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

but I am thinking that it shouldn't be a good idea to set that false. So, what is the alternative here? there error saying that ***'use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.***' but where am I gonna register that thing? thanks !

Also, I am using some AjaxControlToolkit controls inside my usercontrol and some jquery stuff.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
```

before load and bind data in datagrid

Comment: This is correct if the code is trying to change the datasource on the grid.

Comment: It is actually true. I was using un update panel and I was data binding the data source in each postback in the page load.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with ASP.NET 2.0 event validation is that it is all or nothing and a bit heavy handed. I read an [article](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2007/04/23/asp-net-2-0-event-validation.aspx)  that explains what you should do here.

Basically you need to register the child controls of the user control with the event validation engine.

```
C#
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // Register controls for event validation
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(
                c.UniqueID.ToString()
        );
    }
    base.Render(writer);
}

VB
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)

    For Each aControl As Control In Me.Controls
        Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(aControl.UniqueID.ToString)
    Next aControl

    MyBase.Render(writer)
End Sub
```

Now this may not solve your problem because I am not sure how you are returning the string. Another [article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/03/22/asp-net-event-validation-and-invalid-callback-or-postback-argument-again.aspx) explains that the event validation is a combination of the control's unique ID and all the values it can pass back. If you are using the `command` value of a button to pass the text you may have trouble with this task.

If the event that is causing the issue is the click, then registering the controls of the user control should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! Setting EnableEventValidation="true" in the .aspx file and adding this to the code-behind (aspx.cs) works just dandy for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation I was trying to update a GridViews datasource on `page_load` and I forgot to check if the request was a postback, thus my source was trying to change and it threw this error. Once I did the check for post back it worked fine.  Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {
        this.sqlObj = new SqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PdfReceiverConnectionString"].ToString());
        this.populateDataGrid();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your HTML, nested from Tags will also cause that

Comment: This solved it!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can leave it enabled then register your control for event validation. Add the following call in the PreRender or Render page life cycle then your control should work without having to turn off eventValidation:

```
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(this.UniqueID);
```

Comment: gives this error: RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();

Comment: i managed to solve the issue by using the Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(this.UniqueID); in the Render and also putting all gv bindings from page load in !IspostBack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968525/templatefield-button-causing-gridview-invalid-postback/12081309#12081309