# unable to solve Timer_Tick

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have same problem as this question.[se the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764875/se-the-clientscriptmanager-registerforeventvalidation-method-in-order-to-registe) i  havent any problem with `<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>`.I solve it and i try

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Label2.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt32(Label2.Text) - 1));
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Label2.Text) == 0)
        {

            Timer1.Dispose();
            Submit();
        }
}
```

Code work fine means `submit ()` is work if i call from submit button.If its call from `Timer_Tick` its not work.And timer is not stop or dispose.What is a problem plz suggest?

timer:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
                                </asp:Timer>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Remaining Time:(Min)"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="100"></asp:Label>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: can you show your code where you initialize your timer? I suspect you've got something not quite right there. Are any exceptions thrown? Does it ever fire the Timer_Tick method?

Comment: also where in the code is Timer1 declared what is it's access level..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where are you Enabling or Starting the timer on the page? The timer will not automatically start upon page load, you will need to explicitly call Start() or set Enabled = true

Answer (score 0):

```
Label2.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt32(Label2.Text) - 1));
```

Does that line works?

Maybe the if

```
Convert.ToInt32(Label2.Text) == 0
```

doesn't return true